# JavaFX how to assign content to a child node UI controller

Tags: javafx, controlsfx

I have written the following code, where I assigned the MasterNode as a new treeView.

```
MasterDetailPane pane = new MasterDetailPane();
pane.setMasterNode(new TreeView());
pane.setDetailNode(new PropertySheet());
pane.setDetailSide(Side.BOTTOM);
pane.setShowDetailNode(true);
```

Now I want to populate and manipulate that TreeView programmatically.  I think I need to do a pane.getMasterNode()..., but some how I should be able to access that controller and say something like,

```
pane.getMasterNode().setRoot(rootNode);
```

But I can't figure out how to get a hold of the controller, and get it cast as the right type of object in order to assign the rootNode.   How to do I access that buried controller to assign a rootNode?

Comment: You are creating the `TreeNode` yourself, so why not assigning it to a field before setting it as `MasterNode` so you can acces it easier lateron? That way you dont need the cast etc.. Also calling the `MasterNode`/`TreeNode` a `Controller` might be rather confusing, since its something totally different in JavaFX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I did figure it out.  I'm just getting started in javafx, so bear with me.  Simply casting the node to a tree view was all that was required to get the UI class back and make it accessible.

```
TreeView myTree = (TreeView) pane.getMasterNode();
myTree.setRoot(rootNode);
```

And it works as expected.